# 700 audio players inside nested tab interface. Best tab code type (jquery/ajax/etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, audio

Right now we are building a nested tab interface that will actually have 700 audio players (for MP3s) on the same page (nested in various tabs). However, only 1 audio player will be visible at a time and only when you click on the tab itself.

My question, is there a Tab language/code type that you recommend so that there are no loading issues with the browser? In other words, we would like for the tab content to be loaded once clicked (i.e. dynamic/responsive), not beforehand so as to not overload the browser.

Also, we assume HTML5 audio player is better than flash? Looking for the most lightweight option for tabs and audio player.

If it matters this is on a worpdress site.

Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Creating 700 audio players doesn't seem like a best solution in this circumstances, I would rather create one player and append it to active tab, of course with proper source items. If you'll prepare jsfiddle for that I may adjust it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this.  There is no reason for 700 audio players.  You can't play more than 30 or so at a time without breaking most clients.

Only create the audio element when you need it.

I recommend using something like jPlayer which gives you HTML5 audio with a Flash fallback for clients that need it.

Comment: You are saying I can still use the 700 tabs as long as the audio element is created when needed? Could you please expand on a method for doing this? I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: @user2204095 You're using jQuery, so you could simply `$(/* target element here */).append($('<audio>').attr('src', 'http://example.com/something.mp3'));`